# Excel VBA - Export to PDF

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

First of all I am new here so please be kind.

I have created a summary workbook that uses a macro to select a specific range ("A19:W105") from a number of workbooks in a folder and copy the values into the summary workbook. The amount of data in this range varies and sometimes can be 1 row or up to 86 rows. The code works well and is below:

```
 With wsMaster
            erow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            wsTemp.Range("A19:W105").Copy
            .Range("B" & erow).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
 End With
```

I then created an command button to save the summary workbook as PDF. The issue I have run into now is that with the code I have written selects all the blank cells that have been copied over as well. This results in a PDF file that is  multiple pages long, even though only 1 or 2 pages have actual data in them. This code is found below:

```
Dim lastrow As Long
DateStr = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-d")

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Range("B1:X" & lastrow).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF,_ 
        Filename:="K:\AALI\Forecasts\Exported PDF Summary Sheets\"_
        & "(" & DateStr & ") " & "MR Forecast and Budget Summary" & "_" _
        & Comment, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True,_
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Is there a way to select only the range that has actual information in it?

UPDATE 1:
Attached is a screenshot of the worksheet. Everything below the last row of data is "Blank" (no formulas or text), however when the macro copies the information from the other files, some of the values are blank as a result of an IFERROR formula. Does this make a difference? Also when copying the data over I have coded a sort function into the macro, any issues with that?

#### Screenshot of file

[image: Screenshot of file]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot.  Is there blank lines between the data?  Are there blank lines after the data?

Answer (score 1):

First Find out which is last with data with the help of any column which will not contain any blanks. If you want to use `Rows.count` to get the last used row, Make sure that complete sheet on which you have saved a data is blank (There should be nothing except the data).

```
Dim lastrow As Long

If ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value = "" Then
lastrow = 2
Else
lastrow = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
End If
Range("B1:X" & lastrow).Select
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Test.pdf"
```

Use the column which will not contain BLANKS instead of "B" with range object to find end of your data, and change the location and name of the pdf file.

Comment: I still get the multiple pages on the PDF. See the update for a little more information. All  rows beyond 38 in this instance are blank, but is acting as though there is a value associated (ie. _Ctrl_ + _Shift_ + _Down_ finds 'values' up to row 618 even though there are no values associated with that range.

Comment: Try CLEAN & TRIM data.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the empty rows and setting `IgnorePrintAreas` to True do the trick.

```
Dim x As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim DateStr As String


lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 1 To lastrow

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(x)) = 0 Then Rows(x).Hidden = True

Next

DateStr = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-d")
Range("B1:X" & lastrow).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        FileName:="K:\AALI\Forecasts\Exported PDF Summary Sheets\" _
        & "(" & DateStr & ") " & "MR Forecast and Budget Summary" & "_" _
        & Comment, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=True, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Comment: The same issues occur. I added an update to the description. Also I will restate the comment I left under Aditya's post as well:

All rows beyond 38 in this instance are blank, but is acting as though there is a value associated (ie. Ctrl + Shift + Down finds 'values' up to row 618 even though there are no values associated with that range.

Comment: Are you sure that there are no spaces?  I would delete all rows beyond 38 and then save the spreadsheet.